# Apollo Server "JavaScript heap out of memory"

Tags: amazon-ecs, apollo-server, koa

[image]Recently upgraded to Apollo Server 4, not sure if its the cause of this issue but recently upon looking at our ECS monitoring. Noticed spikes of CPU every 8 hours or so

When looking into the logs. Am seeing the below:
[image]

The ECS service:
[image]

Hoping to look for some advice as to how one might dive deeper into this issue

Thanks

Added Datadog Profiling and noticed Segment was taking up a bit of memory so decided to remove that but problem still exists